# How to change SQL Server Analysis Service Log-On account from Any Specific user account to inbuilt account i.e. NT Service \SQLServerOLAP?

Tags: sql, service, sql-server-2012, ssas

I have changed the SQL Server Analysis Service account from In Built account to My system user account. I want to use the previous built in NT Service \SQLSerVER OLAP (Don't remember the exact name, but something similar to it).

I did not find any helpful suggestions how can I get that account.

Please help.

Manoj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure Service Accounts (Analysis Services) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175371%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

This has all the details about the permissions that you'll need to recreate.

Comment: If you need to just change the account it runs under see this page. Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestions. I did not clearly get the solution for the problem by this way because this was some very tedious task to understand the details from the links , But I have found the solution.

Comment: I have to repair SQL Server Analysis service from Control Panel and than it has written few changes in the Configuration log file inside SQL Analysis service. Use the same account from that file and no need to provide password for that account as account will automatically pick the original password .